# How many people who buy $A$ and $B$ book are there?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are $30$ people in a class. People who bought $A$ book buys $B$ book too. The value of people who buys book is $5$ times of people who don't buy any book. How many people who buy $A$ and $B$ book are there?

I'm a bit confused. Can you assist?

My work:

$$A = B$$

Let $A$ and $B$ be $r(1)$. And who don't buy any book is $r(2)$.

$r(1) + r(2) = 30$

So, I can't figure it out more.

Comment: Did I ask it wrong

Comment: Where are you confused? Can you show your work?

Comment: As you wish! I'm going to update it.

Comment: Is it an MCQ or a subjective problem?

Comment: We can compute how many people bought book B, and the people who bought book A are a subset of those who bought book B, but we don't know how big or small a subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \subset B$. So, $B$ contains $A$.

$\implies |A \cap B|=|A|$, $|A \cup B| = |B| $

It does not imply $A=B$.

So, you need to find $|A \cap B|=|A|$

---

$|B|+|B'|=30$

$|B|=5|B'|$

---

We can't find a value for $|A|$, given what we have.

Comment: If we plug this into our equation $|B|=5|B'|$, $6|B'| = 30$, $|B'| = 5$ from $5.5 = 25$, right?

Comment: Yes, but we need a value for $|A \cap B|=|A|$ which we can't get in spite of getting values for $|B|$ and $|B'|$.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not necessarily the case that $A=B$. Everyone who buys book $A$ buys book $B$, but it’s quite possible that someone buys only book $B$.

As currently phrased, the problem doesn’t have a solution because it doesn’t provide enough details. carefully check the source of the problem to make sure you’re copying it correctly.

Comment: Are you sure? $r(1) = 5.r(2)$ If $r(1) + r(2) = 30$, then $6.r(2) = 30$. From that, $r(2) = 5$. as finally, $30 - 5 = 25$.

Comment: As I said in my answer, $A=B$ is wrong, so you can’t use that. You’re also conflating the “value” of a purchase with the number of people who make that purchase, so $r(1)=5r(2)$ doesn’t hold.